# Question regarding SQL Server 2008 R2 installation - 'Server Configuration' phase

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 on my development laptop and am hitting a snag when it gets to the 'Server Configuration' phase.  It's asking me for Windows user account information for the various servies it needs to run.  I'm not sure what to put in, or how to create what it's looking for.  I tried putting in custom account names and passwords in the hope it would create those accounts automatically, but I get an 'Invalid account name or password' error for each.

I know next to nothing when it comes to Windows from an IT perspective, so I'm lost right now.  I found one [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504%28SQL.105%29.aspx), but it's over my head.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't the services run under NETWORK SERVICE? I thought there was an option for that. I *vaguely* recall a button similar to "use same account for all services" and NETWORK SERVICE being an option.

Comment: There is a 'Use same account for all services' button.  There were two low level SQL services listed with existing account names which were not editable.  Would the button simply use that info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's asking you to choose which account you want to use for the SQL services. You can choose the Network Service account, the Local Service account, the Local System account, or a user account that already exists on the local machine or in the domain.

Answer (score 2):

Start -> Run -> lusrmgr.msc

That will open the local users management console. Add a new user for SQL, with any name and password you like. Give that name and password to SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to put in an account that has local administrator access on your laptop.  That could be an account that already exists on your laptop or, if your laptop is joined to an Active Directory domain, a domain account.

This account will be what all of the SQL Server related services use to access various resources on your laptop including the filesystem, the network, etc.

Answer (score 0):

for the time being try entering the local admin account cedentials. That should give it everything it needs, you only really have to create accouts for an enteprise envionment when you need to restrict access to most users. I gather you the only one who uses that laptop, if so this soulution should be fine.